# CoreData could not fulfill a fault occurring with unmodified object.

Tags: ios, core-data

I attempt to access a float value of a NSManagedObject using

```
float f = [managedObject.price floatValue];
```

and get the following error. I thought this error was caused when an object was deleted and you try to manipulate it. I do not update nor delete any properties of the original object. Is there any other reason this error would occur?

```
  2011-07-29 13:02:54.797 AEsir[3760:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x6095d20 <x-coredata://6483BA33-F9AD-436C-91CB-0EE6E07F2FBE/Venue/p7>''
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x35c6464f __exceptionPreprocess + 114
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x31cb9c5d objc_exception_throw + 24
        2   CoreData                            0x30a51e99 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1244
        3   CoreData                            0x30aa69c1 -[NSFaultHandler fulfillFault:withContext:] + 20
        4   CoreData                            0x30aa5789 _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 360
        5   CoreData                            0x30a50f1f _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 58
        6   CoreData                            0x30ab481b _pvfk_16 + 10
        7   AEsir                               0x0000b641 -[VenueListViewController transactionSucceeded:] + 240
        8   Foundation                          0x35f31183 _nsnote_callback + 142
        9   CoreFoundation                      0x35c3320f __CFXNotificationPost_old + 402
        10  CoreFoundation                      0x35bcdeeb _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 118
        11  Foundation                          0x35f2e5d3 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 70
        12  AEsir                               0x00036c67 -[CreditManager finishTransaction:wasSuccessful:] + 170
        13  AEsir                               0x00036d4b -[CreditManager completeTransaction:] + 106
        14  AEsir                               0x00036ffb -[CreditManager paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:] + 246
        15  StoreKit                            0x35970da9 __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 44
        16  CoreFoundation                      0x35bcc3c5 CFArrayApplyFunction + 40
        17  StoreKit                            0x359727f1 -[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:] + 92
        18  StoreKit                            0x35972351 -[SKPaymentQueue _processUpdates:trimUnmatched:] + 860
        19  StoreKit                            0x35971137 -[SKPaymentQueue _transactionUpdatedNotification:] + 98
        20  Foundation                          0x35f31183 _nsnote_callback + 142
        21  CoreFoundation                      0x35c3320f __CFXNotificationPost_old + 402
        22  CoreFoundation                      0x35bcdeeb _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 118
        23  Foundation                          0x35f2e5d3 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 70
        24  AppSupport                          0x35272455 -[CPDistributedNotificationCenter deliverNotification:userInfo:] + 44
        25  AppSupport                          0x35273781 _CPDNDeliverNotification + 204
        26  AppSupport                          0x352721d7 _XDeliverNotification + 122
        27  AppSupport                          0x35268dd7 migHelperRecievePortCallout + 138
        28  CoreFoundation                      0x35c3ba97 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 26
        29  CoreFoundation                      0x35c3d83f __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 166
        30  CoreFoundation                      0x35c3e60d __CFRunLoopRun + 520
        31  CoreFoundation                      0x35bceec3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 230
        32  CoreFoundation                      0x35bcedcb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 58
        33  GraphicsServices                    0x30b5d41f GSEventRunModal + 114
        34  GraphicsServices                    0x30b5d4cb GSEventRun + 62
        35  UIKit                               0x30dd9d69 -[UIApplication _run] + 404
        36  UIKit                               0x30dd7807 UIApplicationMain + 670
        37  AEsir                               0x00008093 main + 70
        38  AEsir                               0x00002d8c start + 52
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the error if something happens with the persistent store e.g. you remove the store from the persistent store manager used by the context.

Most likely, however, the managed object has been deleted but you have retained a reference to it elsewhere.